# Macro stringifies a previous macros identifier instead of its replacement

Tags: c, macros, stringification

Why is `inner_LOAD_ATOM(buffer, ATOM_MAX)` converted to `scanf("%" "ATOM_MAX" "s", x)` but the wrapped version isnt? I would expect ATOM_MAX(identifier) to be replaced by 10 before it is "passed" to `inner_LOAD_ATOM` or `LOAD_LINE` and making the wrapper useless. More elaborated answer why the wrapper is necessary would be very appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ATOM_MAX 10
#define inner_LOAD_ATOM(x, y) scanf("%" #y "s", x)      /* inner part */
#define LOAD_ATOM(x, y) inner_LOAD_ATOM(x, y)           /* wrapper of inner_LOAD_ATOM */


int main(void)
{
    char buffer[ATOM_MAX] = {0, };

    /* wrapped works fine */
    LOAD_ATOM(buffer, ATOM_MAX);        

    /* [Warning] unknown conversion
    type character 'A' in format [-Wformat=] */
    inner_LOAD_ATOM(buffer, ATOM_MAX);

    printf("%s\n", buffer);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to understand that function-like macros don't work like C functions.  There is (almost) no sense of a macro call stack or of forwarding arguments from one macro to another.  Instead, macro expansion proceeds iteratively -- macro is replaced with its expansion, then the expansion is rescanned for further macros to expand.

A function-like macro's arguments are completely macro expanded before being inserted into the macro's replacement text, *except* where they are the operands of the stringification (`#`) or token-pasting (`##`) operator.  Therefore, if you invoke `inner_LOAD_ATOM(buffer, ATOM_MAX)` directly, `ATOM_MAX` is not expanded before the `#` operator is applied.

On the other hand, when you invoke `LOAD_ATOM(buffer, ATOM_MAX)`, the `ATOM_MAX` macro is expanded before `LOAD_ATOM()` is expanded.  The `inner_LOAD_ATOM()` doesn't factor in at that point -- it's just part of the outer macro's replacement text until `LOAD_ATOM()`'s expansion is re-scanned for further macro expansions.

Answer (score 1):

Because on the first pass `#y` will get replaced by `#ATOM_MAX` and stringified. So it won't get expanded on the second pass. Let's just run it manually:

First pass:

```
int main(void)
{
    char buffer[10] = {0, };

    /* wrapped works fine */
    inner_LOAD_ATOM(buffer, 10); // <-- Note - here it ATOM_MAX was expanded in the first pass       

    /* [Warning] unknown conversion
    type character 'A' in format [-Wformat=] */
    scanf("%" "ATOM_MAX" "s", buffer); 

    printf("%s\n", buffer);


    return 0;
}
```

Second pass:

```
int main(void)
{
    char buffer[10] = {0, };

    /* wrapped works fine */
    scanf("%" "10" "s", buffer);        

    /* [Warning] unknown conversion
    type character 'A' in format [-Wformat=] */
    scanf("%" "ATOM_MAX" "s", buffer);   // <----- Not expanded as is interpreted as string

    printf("%s\n", buffer);


    return 0;
}
```